# Notation of a function from a set to a multiset

Tags: functions, notation, multisets

Given two sets $A$ and $B$ and a function $F$ from $B$ to multisets of $A$, e.g.:

\begin{align}
A &= \{x, y, z\} \\
B &= \{b_1, b_2, b_3\} \\
F(b_1) &= \{x,x,y\}\\
F(b_2) &= \{y,z,z\}\\
F(b_3) &= \varnothing\\
\end{align}

Is the following function notation for $F$ correct?

\begin{align}
F &: B \to (A \to \mathbb{N)} 
\end{align}

Comment: If you consider 0 a natural number. Then yes

Comment: And if you only consider finite cardinalities

Comment: @user251257 where do you infer the "finite" part from?

Comment: any number in $\mathbb N$ is finite

Comment: @user251257 what's needed to also express infinite cardinalities?

Comment: $\mathbb N \cup \{ \aleph_0, \dotsc \}$